# Why my server php code cannot receive JSON object from my iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, json

I am trying to send a JSON object containing username and password info from an iOS app to my server for login. However, it seems like the php code never received the JSON object or decoded it correctly. I have tried many different ways to convert JSON object and send to server, but none of them succeeded. I am coding in swift 2 by the way. Any help? THANKS!

Here is my swift code:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "myURL");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

let params : [String : AnyObject] = ["username": username!, "password": password!];
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");

do {
   let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions());
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData;
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    print(jsonString);
    print(request.HTTPBody);

} catch {
    print(error)
}

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    do{
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary

        print(response)
        if let parseJSON = json {
            let resultValue = parseJSON["type"] as? Int
            print("result: \(resultValue)")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
})

task.resume()
```

And here is my php code:

```
require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$fp = fopen("data.txt", "a+");

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data, false);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

fwrite($fp, $data);
fwrite($fp, $json);
fwrite($fp, $username);
fwrite($fp, $password);
fclose($fp);
$returnValue = array();

if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $returnValue["status"] = "error";
    $returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}  

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userType = $dao->passwordAuthentification($username, $password);

if ($userType != null) {
    $returnValue["type"] = (int)$userType;
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
} else {
    $returnValue["type"] = -1;
    $returnValue["message"] = "user is not found";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
}

$dao->closeConnection();
```

Comment: Have you printed `$data` without decoding-it? Also, your `$_POST` values are right?

Comment: I have tried to write $data into a file without decoding it, but nothing appeared in the file.

Comment: I can help you on php side, but I don't know ios, so - if no data is received, I think the problem reside in ios script. I'm sorry. You can also try to write into file variables like `$_REQUEST` and `$_POST` ( `$data = print_r($_REQUEST, True);`, then write `$data` to file )

Comment: OK, I found the problem. It is the permission problem that I cannot write to the file. I have changed mode for all parent folders in the file path to 777. Now that it can write to the file. Thanks anyway!